# KubeDNS namespace lookups failing

Tags: kubernetes

#### Stack

- Environment: Azure
- Type of install: Custom
- Base OS: Centos 7.3
- Docker: 1.12.5

The first thing I will say is that I have this same install working in ***AWS*** with the *same configuration* files for `apiserver`, `manager`, `scheduler`, `kubelet`, and `kube-proxy`.

#### Here is the kubelet config:

```
/usr/bin/kubelet \
  --require-kubeconfig \
  --allow-privileged=true \
  --cluster-dns=10.32.0.10 \
  --container-runtime=docker \
  --docker=unix:///var/run/docker.sock \
  --network-plugin=kubenet \
  --kubeconfig=/var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig \
  --serialize-image-pulls=true \
  --cgroup-root=/ \
  --system-container=/system \
  --node-status-update-frequency=4s \
  --tls-cert-file=/var/lib/kubernetes/kubernetes.pem \
  --tls-private-key-file=/var/lib/kubernetes/kubernetes-key.pem \
  --v=2
```

#### Kube-proxy config:

```
/usr/bin/kube-proxy \
  --master=https://10.240.0.6:6443 \
  --kubeconfig=/var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig \
  --proxy-mode=iptables \
  --v=2
```

#### Behavior:

Login to any of the pods on any node:

```
nslookup kubernetes 10.32.0.10
Server:    10.32.0.10
Address 1: 10.32.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes': Try again
```

#### What does work is:

```
nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local. 10.32.0.10
Server:    10.32.0.10
Address 1: 10.32.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local.
Address 1: 10.32.0.1 kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
```

So I figured out that on azure, the ***resolv.conf*** looked like this:

```
; generated by /usr/sbin/dhclient-script
  search ssnci0siiuyebf1tqq5j1a1cyd.bx.internal.cloudapp.net 
  10.32.0.10
  options ndots:5
```

If I added the search domains of *`default.svc.cluster.local`* *`svc.cluster.local cluster.local`*.

Everything started working and I understand why.

However, this is problematic because for every namespace I create, I would need to manage the ***resolv.conf***.

This does not happen when I deploy in Amazon so I am kind of stumped on why it is happening in Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kubelet has a command line flag, `cluster-domain` which it looks like you're missing. See the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kubelet/)

Add `--cluster-domain=cluster.local` to your kubelet command start up, and it should start working as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That fixed it.